# not able to boot any OS Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

My system is Samsung laptop with a 128GB samsung ssd I've installed Ubuntu as dual-boot with Windows from live USB. After restart, My system does not boot to any of the OS. I did a `boot-repair` from live USB. Here is the result:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10645082/

How can I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows?

Note: I don't have any data to save, So I can also reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: have You changed the `boot-order` in your BIOS unplug your USB after installation

Comment: if i press F2 or something else, i get no bios any longer... only a blue screen like a bios with two tabs: Boot Info, App Info. But these tabs are empty.... so there seems to be no more bios

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in the boot-repair log and your description makes me think, that the cause of the issue lies  most likely with the configuration of your BIOS. Do you have Legacy BIOS or UEFI BIOS? Was/Is Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: ive got a legacy bios. before i installed linux ive disabled secure boot and fast boot. Also, and that is the great failure now, i disabled in the boot menu the hdd. After this config, i installed linux without any erros. but after restart, nothing happens, cause hdd is deactivated in bios. But i cant access bios an longer... i allways get the boot menu with no entries...

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you must change some configurations under BIOS :

- advanced section : disable fastbios
- boot section     : change to CSM_OS

And also look at this article:

[booting-linux-via-uefi-can-brick-some-samsung-laptops](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2026807/booting-linux-via-uefi-can-brick-some-samsung-laptops.html)

Comment: shit... i think exactly this happened: i try to boot ubuntu with uefi... now i cant access the bios any longer. But ubuntu live works! So i try to get a bios reset...

Comment: If the problem is brick and If your laptop still have warranty you can claim it.